# struts2-jquery datepicker tag not loading in struts2-jquery tabbedpannel tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a page `index.jsp`, I've used struts2-jquery tabbedpannel tag in this jsp to display another two JSPs (`first.jsp` & `second.jsp`) as tabs.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<sj:head />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sj:tabbedpanel 
        id="remotetabs" 
        selectedTab="0" 
        show="true" 
        hide="'fade'" 
        collapsible="true" 
        sortable="true">

            <sj:tab id="tab1" href="first.jsp" label="First JSP"/>
            <sj:tab id="tab2" href="second.jsp" label="Second JSP"/>

    </sj:tabbedpanel>
</body>
</html>
```

Another two JSPs contain a form each with struts2-datepicker tag. Here is one of them...

**first.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/view.css" media="all">


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>First JSP</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
    <s:form action="firstAction" >
            <sj:datepicker 
                key="timeStamp" 
                name="timeStamp"  
                label="Time Stamp" 
                timepicker="true" 
                displayFormat="yy-mm-dd" 
                timepickerFormat="HH:mm"/>
            <s:submit value="Submit"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, the first time `index.jsp` is loaded, struts2-jquery datepicker tag on first.jsp works fine, but as I switch to second tab; which will load `second.jsp` in AJAX *(second.jsp contains same code as first.jsp)* struts2-jquery datepicker tag on `second.jsp` doesn't work.

Now, when I switch back to First Tab to display `first.jsp`, struts2-jquery datepicker tag doesn't work either. It just stops working after first load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling JSP pages, while you should call Struts2 Actions.

Struts2 is MVC. You souldn't call a View from a View, you should instead call a Controller that will dispatch to a View.

The first time, it works because the variables feeding struts and struts-jquery tags in `first.jsp` and `second.jsp` are taken from `IndexAction`.

You should instead define `FirstAction` and `SecondAction` and call them through AJAX in the `href` attribute:

```
<s:url var="firstActionUrl" action="first" namespace="/" />
<sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{#firstActionUrl}" label="First JSP"/>

<s:url var="secondActionUrl" action="second" namespace="/" />
<sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{#secondActionUrl}" label="Second JSP"/>
```